# How to append list in multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, multi-index

How can I append a list to a specific row in a Multi-Index DataFrame?

```
index = [("s", "1"),("s", "2"),("s", "3"),("s", "4"),("s", "5"), ("c", "1"),("c", "2"),("c", "3"),("c", "4"),("c", "5")]
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index)
df = pd.DataFrame({"I1":[11,12,13,14,15,10,22,33,44,55],"I2":[0,1,2,3,4,5,1,1,1,1]}, index=multi_index)
df
```

result of this code

```
        I1  I2
s   1   11  0
    2   12  1
    3   13  2
    4   14  3
    5   15  4
c   1   10  1
    2   22  1
    3   33  1
    4   44  1
    5   55  1
```

I want append list x = [16,17,18,19] in df.loc["s"].loc['In1']

to get

```
        I1  I2
s   1   11  0
    2   12  1
    3   13  2
    4   14  3
    5   15  4
    6   16  NaN
    7   17  NaN
    8   18  NaN
    9   19  NaN
c   1   10  1
    2   22  1
    3   33  1
    4   44  1
    5   55  1
```

How I can Do this ?

Answer (score 1):

One option using [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
x = [16,17,18,19]

last_max = int(df.loc['s'].index.max())

tmp = pd.DataFrame({'I1': x})
tmp.index = (tmp.index+last_max).astype(str)

out = (pd.concat([df, pd.concat([tmp], keys='s')])
         .sort_index(level=0, sort_remaining=False, kind='stable')
      )
```

Output:

```
     I1   I2
c 1  10  5.0
  2  22  1.0
  3  33  1.0
  4  44  1.0
  5  55  1.0
s 1  11  0.0
  2  12  1.0
  3  13  2.0
  4  14  3.0
  5  15  4.0
  5  16  NaN
  6  17  NaN
  7  18  NaN
  8  19  NaN
```

Alternative suggested by @cs95:

```
pd.concat([df,
           pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['I1'],
                        index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['s'],np.arange(1,len(x)+1)
                                                          + int(df.loc['s'].index[-1])
                                                         ]))
          ]).sort_index()
```

Comment: Shorter: `pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['I1'], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['s'], np.arange(1,len(x)+1) + int(df.loc['s'].index[-1]) ]))]).sort_index()`

Comment: @cs95 I hesitated to use a mutiindex directly, but you're right, this is also probably more efficient :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a new DataFrame with the list `x` and the corresponding multi-index values and then `concat` this new DataFrame with the original DataFrame.

Following is the updated code:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Your existing DataFrame setup
index = [("s", "1"), ("s", "2"), ("s", "3"), ("s", "4"), ("s", "5"), ("c", "1"), ("c", "2"), ("c", "3"), ("c", "4"), ("c", "5")]
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index)
df = pd.DataFrame({"I1":[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 10, 22, 33, 44, 55], "I2":[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1]}, index=multi_index)

# The list to append
x = [16, 17, 18, 19]

# Creating new index tuples for the list 'x'
new_index = [("s", str(i)) for i in range(6, 6 + len(x))]

# Creating a new DataFrame with the list 'x'
new_df = pd.DataFrame({"I1": x}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_index))

# Concatenating the original DataFrame with the new DataFrame
df = pd.concat([df, new_df]).sort_index()

print(df)
```

Output:

```
     I1   I2
c 1  10  5.0
  2  22  1.0
  3  33  1.0
  4  44  1.0
  5  55  1.0
s 1  11  0.0
  2  12  1.0
  3  13  2.0
  4  14  3.0
  5  15  4.0
  6  16  NaN
  7  17  NaN
  8  18  NaN
  9  19  NaN
```

Comment: `append` is deprecated has has been removed in pandas 2.0, you should not use it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to insert the new indices for the new values for the indices and then assign the new values to `I1` using `loc`

```
x = [16, 17, 18, 19]
s_last = int(df.loc["s"].index[-1])
new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [["s"], map(str, range(s_last + 1, s_last + len(x) + 1))]
)
df = df.reindex(df.index.union(new_idx))
df.loc[new_idx, "I1"] = x

print(df)

       I1   I2
c 1  10.0  5.0
  2  22.0  1.0
  3  33.0  1.0
  4  44.0  1.0
  5  55.0  1.0
s 1  11.0  0.0
  2  12.0  1.0
  3  13.0  2.0
  4  14.0  3.0
  5  15.0  4.0
  6  16.0  NaN
  7  17.0  NaN
  8  18.0  NaN
  9  19.0  NaN
```